# How to serialize a specific object in Kryo

Tags: java, apache-spark, kryo

I do such a Kryo test, the code is like:

```
//// write stage
// load file
File bamfile = new File(args[0]);
Reader reader = open(bamfile);

Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
kryo.register(Some.class);
Output output = new Output(new FileOutputStream(args[1]));

// write all the records
for (Record record : reader) {
    Some writeObj= new Some();
    some.set(record);
    kryo.writeObject(output, writeObj);
}

reader.close();
output.close();

//// read stage
Input input = new Input(new FileInputStream(args[2]));
// read all the records
while (true) {
    try {
        Some readObj = kryo.readObject(input, Some.class);
        // do some
    } catch(KryoException ke) {
        break;
    }
}

input.close();
```

And I have implement the KryoSerializable interface, the code is like:

```
public class Some implements KryoSerializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8212888201641460871L;

    private static final RecordCodec lazyCodec = new RecordCodec();
    private Record record;

    public Record    get()         { return record; }
    public void      set(Record r) { record = r; }

    /* Kryo */
    @Override
    public void read(Kryo kryo, Input input) {
        lazyCodec.setInputStream(input);
        record = lazyCodec.decode();
    }
    @Override
    public void write(Kryo kryo, Output output) {
        final RecordCodec codec = new RecordCodec();
        codec.setOutputStream(output);
        codec.encode(record);
    }
}
```

** the `RecordCodec` class is used to compress the record data.

But I found that, the intermediate output file is much larger than the original loaded file! (loaded file: 220m, intermediate output file: 870m) I think if Kryo invokes the `write` method in `Some` class, the intermediate output file should be about 300-400m, rather than 870m.

So I want to ask, if Kryo would invoke the read and write method in specific class? It doesn't seem to be much compact as I think, do I make some mistakes?